# Calling a function within foreach?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been working on a Wordpress theme project over the past few days and I've been stuck on how to get a dynamic options page running properly using OOP (I'm primarily a Theme Developer, not a PHP scripter).

```
    <?php
    $footerpage = new optionpage;
    $footerpage->title = 'Footer';
    $footerpage->titleprint = ' Footer Options';
    $footerpage->slug = 'footer';
    $footerpage->html = array(
 '1' => array(
 'type' => 'textarea',
 'class' => 'large-text',
 'name' => 'html',
 'title' => 'HTML',
 'description' => 'Type in whatever HTML you\'d like to see in the footer here:',
 ),
 '2' => array(
 'type' => 'input',
 'class' => 'large-text',
 'name' => 'background-color',
 'title' => 'Background Color',
 'description' =>  ' Choose a Background Color:'
 ),

);

    class optionpage {

 public $title;
 public $titleprint;
 public $slug;
 public $html = array();

 ......
 ......
 ......

 public function ab_settings() {

 register_setting( $this->slug, 'ab_options');
 add_settings_section('ab_section', '', array(&$this, 'ab_do_titleprint'),  'ab_' . $this->slug . '_options', 'ab_options' );

 foreach ($this->html as $key => $html) {
 add_settings_field( $key, $html['title'], array(&$this, 'ab_do_htmlprint' ), 'ab_' . $this->slug . '_options', 'ab_section');
 }

 }


 public function ab_do_htmlprint() {
 $html = $this->html[$key];
 ?>

 <p><?php echo $html['description'] ?></p>
 <<?php echo $html['type'] ?> 
 id="<?php echo $html['id'] ?>"
 class="<?php echo $html['class'] ?>"
 name="<?php echo $html['name'] ?>">
 <?php get_option ($html['name'])?>
 </<?php echo $html['type'] ?>> 
 <?php
 }

 ......
 ......
 ?>
```

In this code example, I'm trying to get the function ab_do_htmlprint to recognize the foreach expressions where it's been called, because the function is going to be called as many times as needed in the foreach loop.

I've tried several things, like appending a variable to the function name, but that would require multiple functions of the same code, just with a different name. I also tried passing various variables by reference and such, however they weren't working either, and I may not have been doing that correctly, if they're even needed.

Anyway to accomplish this efficiently?

Comment: i dont follow.  how does the behavior of ab_do_htmlprint need to differ depending on where its called from?  My hunch is a simple argument, but I don't really understand the specifics

Comment: What I want is to have the function ab_do_htmlprint print the HTML of each option that I place inside the multidimensional array. Each time ab_do_htmlprint is called inside the foreach loop, each option will be displayed on the option page I create. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to pass an argument to ab_do_htmlprint. [add_settings_field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) has parameter for that, do:

```
  add_settings_field( $key, $html['title'], array(&$this, 'ab_do_htmlprint' ), 'ab_' . $this->slug . '_options', 'ab_section', array($key));
```

then:

```
  public function ab_do_htmlprint($key) {
    $html = $this->html[$key];
```

etc.

Comment: I tried modifying the code to the above, however this gives me a "Warning: call_user_func(Array) [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback " error.

Comment: I got it to work, I just had to remove the array code at the end, as WP recognized that last argument in add_settings_field was already in an array. This was very close, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have an array of values that you want to show in a group on the admin screen as options.

Maybe the shortest example is what i posted here: http://swiftthemes.com/forums/showthread.php?383-SWIFT-on-a-WordPRess-MU-install/page2

p.s. post WordPress questions on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com : more WordPress Experts!

Comment: Essentially that's it, however I'm using the Settings API, and trying to accomplish this from an object-oriented perspective, so I don't have re-copy and paste the add_settings_field code every time I want to add a new option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Wordpress api, so please verify a few assumptions I have. (I know this is not an answer, but I do not want to put as a comment for readability)

1) `ab_settings()` is called somewhere?
2) Is the section you are having issues with?

```
 foreach ($this->html as $key => $html) {
   add_settings_field( $key, $html['title'], array(&$this, 'ab_do_htmlprint' ), 
   'ab_' . $this->slug . '_options', 'ab_section');
 }
```

3) `$key` is magically available or do you need to provide it as an argument?

```
 public function ab_do_htmlprint() {
    $html = $this->html[$key];`
```

Also, the format of your `ab_do_htmlprint` function is very hard to read and could be a source of error. Try using [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) notation or purely PHP strings

ex) Instead of

```
 public function ab_do_htmlprint() {
 $html = $this->html[$key];
 ?>

 <p><?php echo $html['description'] ?></p>
 <<?php echo $html['type'] ?> 
 id="<?php echo $html['id'] ?>"
 class="<?php echo $html['class'] ?>"
 name="<?php echo $html['name'] ?>">
 <?php get_option($html['name'])?>
 </<?php echo $html['type'] ?>> 
 <?php
 }
```

as

```
 public function ab_do_htmlprint() {
   $html = $this->html[$key];
   $output = "<p>{$html['description']}</p>";
   $output .= "<{$html['type']} id=\"{$html['id']}\"";
   $output .= " class=\"{$html['class']}\"";
   $output .= " name=\"{$html['name']}\">";
   get_option( $html['name'] );
   $output .= "</{$html['type']}>"; 
   echo $output;
 }
```

Comment: 1) Yeah, it is, sorry, I didn't post the entire script. It's being called through an add_action function.

Comment: 2)It might be the section, I'm not sure, I've tried several things, including changing some elements there.

Comment: 3) The code inside ab_do_htmlprint works fine, as I tried appending the $key to the end inside foreach, and I was able to call each individual function fine: ab_do_html1();

Comment: Yeah, that ab_do_htmlprint is the callback function. Is it not possible to generate that callback function dynamically? I'm just trying to get this part working first.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but have you tried `$this` instead of `&$this` for the callback combined with adding the `..., array($key));`?